# What is the actual data transfer rate for the magnetic disk with the given specifications?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, performance, computer-architecture, data-transfer

I saw the question bellow in a Computer Organization Practice Book for University exams.

`Its given that, a magnetic disk has the following specifications:`

> Number of tracks = 1024
> Number of sectors/track = 512
> Bytes/Sector = 512
>   Disk Rotation Speed = 7200 RPM
> Seek time = 9ms

The question given: 
`What is the data transfer rate?`
The answer given: `30GBPS`
My answer: `30MBPS`

---

My method of doing it:

> Rotation speed: 7200RPM
>  So, 7200 rotations in 60 sec
>  1 rotation in 60/7200 sec.
>  Now, in 1 rotation only 1 track is read
> 1 track = 512 sectors = 512*512 bytes.
>   So, in 1 rotation 512*512 bytes is read.
>  i.e. In 1 Rotation 256 KB is read [ since, 512*512 bytes =256*1024 bytes ]
>  Thus, In 60/7200 sec 256 KB is read
> In 1 sec 256*7200/60 KB is read
> i.e 256*120 KB = 30 * 1024 KB = 30 MB
>  So, data transfer rate according to me: 30 MBPS.

---

But the explanation given in the book considered that in 1 rotation all tracks are read,
 i.e In 1 rotation 1024*512*512 bytes is read and this is how they are getting the answer as 30 GBPS.

**Kindly help me out here. Am I right? Or is the book correct?**

Comment: Wow, 30 GB in 1 second. That's even faster than PCI-Express connected SSD cards.

Comment: hahaha, fortunately it is just a university question :P
But, am I correct?

Comment: 30 MB/sec sounds about right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a technical point, a hard drive is a record shaped.  The outer track has significantly more data in it than the inner track.  The outer track of a hard drive maybe 80mb/s but the inner track could be 40.